# DXF to MAX conversion in ORCAD 10.5

Tags: pcb, layout, orcad, dxf

I'm trying to convert my board outline .dxf file to .max for Orcad 10.5. I applied exactly the same steps as described in OrCad Help; however, I obtain nothing but an empty page at the end process. If anyone using Orcad 10.5 still exists, it'll be very helpful.

Thanks.

**Answer:** If it happens to anyone, try saving .dxf in IntelliCad with older version of AutoCad.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem today. Please check the following:

1. When you import a dxf file take care of the following: Today I imported from solidwork a draw from dxf with the name ("Example.dxf" in solidwork format .sldrt) Check the extension of the file (dxf)
2. When you import, select the dxf an click in "**Interact**", if the page is a empty page without any draw you have a mistake in the format of the file. (Not a dxf)
3. If you are able to see the lines of the footprint, select the lines and click "**convert to max**" I usually convert all the lines to "**silkscreen component**" in **TOP layer**. Normally it make a alert but I don't mind because then in the library editor I convert them to silkscreen top, and I delete the useless lines.

*(In our work we still use ORCAD 10.5 because this is the only program that our boss know. However we are going to migrate to another program. Any one know a profesional suite with the maximun possibilities?)*

I hope it help you.

Comment: dxf files are ascii text, not binary. Here's the first few lines from one:   0
SECTION
  2
HEADER
  9
$ACADVER
  1
AC1009
999
I-DEAS Drafting Master Series 7 Not Encoded
  9
$EXTMIN
 10
0.0
 20
0.0
  9
$EXTMAX

Comment: Empty page is not the one in VisualCADD in my case. I convert .dxf drawing by doing exactly the same thing you described. Exit VisualCADD. Don't save. AFter this point, I'm trying to open .max file as always. LayoutPlus->File->Open->xxxx.max . And empty page I obtained. Is that something wrong here? @RaulRiveroleo

Comment: In addition, OrCad 16.5 created no problem with the same .dxf files.

Comment: Mmmm when this happen me, it's normally because I didn't choose in "Convert to max". Layer = TOP and very important silkscreen component or component silkscreen. Can you try it?. I wrote it bad in the answer. (i will correct it)

Comment: It was due to the version of AutoCad that .dxf was created. Thanks for your answer.